# unable to access the var variable, scopes in js

Tags: javascript

I tried with 2 scenarios , In one I could access data variable and other couldn't. need clarification for clearing my scopes concept
Scenario 1 : data not accessible

```js
function test() {
  var data = "from Test";
  secondFunction();
}

function secondFunction() {
  return function() {
    console.log(data);
  }();
}

test();
```

Scenario 2: data is accessible

```js
function test1() {
  var data = "from Test1";
  var secondFunction1 = function() {
    return function() {
      console.log(data);
    }()
  }
  secondFunction1();
}

test1();
```

Comment: There are lots of tutorial for same. Also lots of good answers .

Comment: In your second case, you are creating a closure which remembers the value passed in at the time of creating it. In the first case, you are trying to access the variable which is local to `test()` function.

Comment: you can have look to my answer once , if you get information you are asking please do upvote/accept answer

Comment: let me know if you need more detail

Answer (score 0):

you need to increase scope of you variable to `window` object , than it will work. 
In your current code scope of variable is limited to the function only. so you cannot access variable outside function.

something like will declare variable at larger scope, in below it declare variable at window object so it get accessible to all functions.

```
window.data = 1;
```

if you do like this than it is accessible in given window.

Globals are generally to be avoided. You should define variables within the scope of functions.

---

In your scenario in second case its working because `data` is in scope of given function , and in first case `data` is in scope of first function. that is reason it working in second case but not in first case.

in second case

```
function test1() {
  var data = "from Test1";
  var secondFunction1 = function() {
    return function() {
      console.log(data);
    }()
  }
  secondFunction1();
}
```

if you see you `secondFuction1` is able to get data because the scope is larger , both are part of  `test1()` .

Anything that is not a primitive type (undefined, null, number, string, boolean) is an object (or an instance) in JavaScript. That means function inherits from object . Object instances can contain more instances which can be functions.

so if you go by above statement in OOD way, than in you case `test1()` is object and in that object you have property called `data` and function called `secondFuction1()`, and in OOD function can access property of object , so that is reason its working in you second case.

Comment: doesn't answer his question

Comment: @nikamanish - from question i think he wants to know how to increase scope of variable right ? thats why I told him to increase scope of variable

Comment: he wants to know why scenario 1 is not working and scenario 2 is.

Comment: @nikamanish- i explain in my updated answer...let me write more

Comment: @nikamanish -- I updated lot now , i hope OP understand why it working in case two